# PHP code not displaying when testing code

Tags: php, sql, database

I am attempting to try and save user input in a form based upon important pieces of information like Name, Prayer Request, Phone Number, etc. The idea is a person navigates to the web page and then fills out the information and then clicks a submit button which then saves the data to the database. Whenever I attempt to test the page literally nothing pulls up. I have looked over my code numerous times and cannot find the problem. I had a rough template to base my PHP off of. Within it there is a "Show all" button which does not need to be on the page at all. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. My code (including the "show all" button code) can be found below:

```
<?php
$Req_F_Name = $_POST["Req_F_Name"]; 
$Reg_L_Name = $_POST["Reg_L_Name"]; 
$Reg_Phone = $_POST["Reg_Phone"]; 
$Reg_Email= $_POST["Reg_Email"]; 
$Reg_Request = $_POST["Reg_Request"]; 
$Reg_Address_1= $_POST["Reg_Address_1"];

if ($Submit) { 
$conn = mysql_connect('XXXXXX','XXXX','XXXXXX','prayer')             or 
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error()); 
//select the database 
$db = mysql_select_db("prayer");

$query = "INSERT INTO Request VALUES     ('".$Req_F_Name."','".$Reg_L_Name."','".$Reg_Phone."','".$Reg_Email."','".$Reg_Request."','    ".$Reg_Address_1."')"or die(mysql_error()); 
echo "Your Query was successfully stored in the database :)";

mysql_close($conn); 
}

if ($Show_All_Records) {

//establish connection to mysql 
$conn = mysql_connect('XXXXXX','XXXXXX','XXXXXX','prayer')
or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error()); 
echo "Connected to MySql".'<br>'.'<br>';

//select the database 
$db = mysql_select_db("prayer"); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'Request'",$conn);

//display the results 
echo 'First Name:', $Req_F_Name ,'<br>' 
. 'Last Name:', $Reg_L_Name ,'<br>' 
. 'Phone Number:', $Reg_Phone ,'<br>' 
. 'Email:', $Reg_Email ,'<br>' 
. 'Prayer Request:', $Reg_Request ,'<br>' 
. 'Address:', $Reg_Address_1 ,'<br>'.'<br>';

//grabbing all data from the table 
echo 'Your Query was succesfully stored in the database :)';

while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
echo ''.$myrow["Req_F_Name"].' <br> '.$myrow["Reg_L_Name"].' <br>'.$myrow["Reg_Phone"].' <br> '.$myrow["Reg_Email"].' <br> '.$myrow["Reg_Request"].' <br>  '.$myrow["Reg_Address_1"].' <br>'; 
} 
mysql_close($conn); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: I am not sure if you are learning PHP by tutorials or by courses, but you are using deprecated `mysql()` functions. Please use [`PDO`](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (preferred) or [`mysqli()`](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead. And check for recent tutorials or mention it to your instructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this for connection

```
$conn = mysql_connect('XXXXXX','XXXX','XXXXXX')             or 
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error()); 
//select the database 
$db = mysql_select_db("prayer",$conn);
```